# How to custom sort based on user interests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the existing product controller, we are sorting products based on price.

```
def index
  @products = Product.all.order(price: :asc)
  @products = @products.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
end
```

Now, I would like to change the sorting so that we will user interests. The over all sorting policy will be like this:

1. items belonging to user interested categories will be listed at top. Remaining items will be listed afterwards.
2. Within user interested grouping, products shall be ordered based on price. (similar approach for the non interested grouping).

Users Table

```
id  name    interested_categories   
1   Alice   [ 10, 11 ]  
2   Bruce   [ 11 ]  
3   Carol   [ 10, 12 ]
```

Categories Table

```
id  category_name       
10  School      
11  Kitchen     
12  Camping
```

Products Table

```
id  product_name price category_id
1   pencil       2     10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
def index
  filtered_products = Product.where(category_id: current_user.interested_categories)
  all_products = Product.where.not(category_id: current_user.interested_categories).order(price: :asc)
  @final_products = (filtered_products+all_products).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
end
```

then your views take the `@final_products` or just change the variable into `@products`

Comment: This will return the products twice, so there will be duplicates in the list

Answer (score 0):

```
filtered_products = Product.where(category_id: current_user.interested_categories).to_a.sort_by { |product| [product.category, product.price] }
remaining_products = Product.where.not(category_id: current_user.interested_categories).to_a.sort_by { |product| product.price } 
@products = filtered_products + remaining_products.paginate
```

Converting to Array allows you to use `sort_by` to sort by two criteria.